# Internet/ConnectionSharing Nat in Ubuntu using 2 network cards

Tags: networking, routes, ubuntu-12.04

I have an ubuntu 12.0.4.5 LTS. Two network cards are installed. eth1 is configure for internet. with address 10.232.64.x. The seconde eth0 has a fixed ip 192.168.0.100. This is for the local network.  Clients connect via this card to get services.  The problem is ..once the internal card eth0 is online the internet connection stops working.  I am current using this guide line to fix it.. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing  But Any help could stil be appreicated. And you can as well upgrade the question if you dont mind. Thanks

Comment: Any Idea how I might solve this problem?

Comment: Hi experts . I just solved the problem .. what did the trick is just route change of the defualt .. with the command route add default dev eth1. So Would you please remove the downgrade fo the question.?

Answer (score 0):

Simple command to allow internet traffic. in my condition is `route add default dev eth1` Please restart your network with the `command sudo service network-manager restart` . This will do the trick